# Get PropertyChangeListener notification on static variables (class variables)

Tags: java, static, propertychangelistener

In my code I need to know when a specific static variables change is value. I know that in Java I can register myself as listener for the instance variables but I can' t do that with the static (class) variables. Can anyone have workaround for this problem? Thanks

Comment: First question really is: why is the variable static? And isn't that going to cause synchronisation problems? It just sounds suspicious that you should need such a thing.

Comment: Hi. I explain my problem: I' ve a static method that starts a new Thread and it perform some operation on my db. In that method I need to update a variable that rapresent the progress during this operation that I need to notify to the user via JProgressBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always wrap your static variable with static accessors and add code in those accessors.

Comment: Ok, but I can' t register myself as Listenr with the addPropertyChangeListener method to that static variable. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you access the static variable.  If you use a static setter method to change it, and keep the variable private, it's easy:

```
public class Foo {
   private static int bar = 0;

   private static PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport =
       new PropertyChangeSupport(Foo.class);

   public static void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
       propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public static void setBar(int bar) {
       int oldVal = Foo.bar;
       Foo.bar = bar;
       propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("bar", oldVal, Foo.bar);
   }
}
```

Of course, it's likely you'll want setBar to be a synchronized method in case multiple threads want to set the value, you probably want all the listeners notified before someone else can change the value again, but that depends on your requirements.

Comment: I try to use this method but in the PropertyChangeSupport there isn't a costructor without parameter but there's one that takes an Object as parameter.

Comment: Another problem is that you cannot use this.bar in a static method!

Comment: sorry about that, use the class object.  I have edited the solution

Comment: i probably should have put this code to the compiler.  I have edited the solution again.  That being said, you could easily have corrected the issue yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the edited code. I try to adapt it for my class and check if it works. Thanks a lot!